# Chat bug? Pings and replies time out

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I'm experiencing a strange bug. If I add a ping (`@user`) in my chat message, or reply to a specific message, then the message times out:

[image]

Ordinary messages go through just fine.

Comment: I also had this bug at the same time in the same room. However, it seems to have cleared up already.

Comment: Ohh it's bug. I think it's my ISP fault.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We just deployed some fixes to chat that necessitated some database changes. I *thought* that the builds were configured to run migrations automatically but, of course, I didn't confirm that. Chat's codebase is one of the oldest around here and it hasn't had a lot of changes, in particular *any* changes at all to the database in recent times. So I hit build, the code expected a new column to be there and then we started throwing an exceptions everytime we tried to read from the `Users` table.

I've run the migrations by hand and I'm working on fixing the production build to run migrations by itself like it should.

Apologies for the inconvenience!

Comment: Just curious, what kind of fixes were you deploying?

Comment: Fixes were for employee-only rooms; notably re-instating full name and out of office notifications. Nothing user-facing I’m afraid...